# Elegant way to store data inside tkinter.listbox object / option

Tags: python, tkinter

I have an instance of two different "Listbox" objects
I save each of them in a different reference name

example:

```
l1 = tkinter.Listbox(exampleFrame)
l2 = tkinter.Listbox(exampleFrame)

l1.setvar("check", "1")
l2.setvar("check", "2")

print("var is - " + l1.getvar("check"))
```

the problem is whenever I call getvar of l1 the output will be the var of l2

```
output:
var is - 2
```

I can assume from this result that the Listbox setvar/getvar functions are staticmethod for all Listbox objects?

if so is there any option to store data for each Listbox object with built-in functions?

my goal is to be able to store an id for each listbox option
for example:

```
    Listbox1:
        Albert
        Michel
        Drake
```

will store the id of each user option inside a var.
so when I call the insert method
I store the user.id for each index in the setvar

```
l1.insert(index, user.name)
l1.setvar("var_"+index, user.id)
```

so when I call getvar("var_"+index)
I'll get the ID of the selected user

the current solution will work good only if I have one listbox in my entire project.

any good solution to store data for multi listbox objects?

-- Edit --

What I've tried to achieve is an option to store more values inside a Listbox option

Example:

```
    l1 = Listbox(frame)
    l1.insert(0, 'Drake')
    l1.insert(1, 'Jacob')
```

so instead of having only the index and the string in the Listbox I'll have more stored data of each option.

@1966bc suggested to create a dict and use the option index as the key
so if I want to store more data in example for Drake I can do something like:

```
l1.anydictname = {}
l1.anydictname[0] = {'Name' : 'Drake', 'data' : 'moredata'}
```

so now I can check data of Drake I can use Drake list index and point for the data as l1.anydictname[index].data or name or whatever data I'm storing inside.

Thanks, works like magic. If someone have even a cleaner way of doing it you may suggest

Comment: I am finding it hard to understand. Can you be a little more precise on what you want to achieve?

Comment: `setvar()` is a common widget function with first argument as the variable name.  So you are setting the same variable.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Tkinter - How to assign variable to currently selected item in Listbox?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20274252/tkinter-how-to-assign-variable-to-currently-selected-item-in-listbox)

Comment: @JacksonPro I need to attach the user.id for each user inside the list, Listbox can contain only two variables which is "index" and "string", I need to set another variable for each option an hidden one that will contain the id of the user. I've done it using the setvar inside the Listbox, but setvar is a staticmethod for the Listbox class and not the instance, is there elegant way of doing it for each instance? or any other option to store another argument for a Listbox option?

Comment: You can use an attribute to store the user id: `l1.userid = {}`, then `l1.userid[index] = user.id`.  However if you delete items in the listbox, you need to synchronize the `userid` dict.  If the username is unique, use username as the key.

Comment: @acw1668 will try that and post an update if worked correctly

Comment: I've answeered two questions that does similar to what you are looking for, [first](https://stackoverflow.com/a/65518165/13382000) and [second](https://stackoverflow.com/a/65226392/13382000)

Comment: @acw1668 Yes, it worked correctly.  thanks for pointing me that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I understand correctly, to do what you want you have to associate the listbox index with a dictionary.

I attach a working example
When you select a line of listbox you get something as

> on_listbox_select: index = 2, pk = 3 values = Drake

where index is the listbox index and pk is the id of the selected record.

In the example I've populate the listbox with an immaginary recordset composed of a primary key, a name and a field to enhance its status

> rs = [(1,"Albert",1), (2,"Michel",1), (3,"Drake",0), (4,"Alan",1),(5,"George",0)]

```
#!/usr/bin/python3
import sys
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import ttk
from tkinter import messagebox


class App(tk.Tk):
    """Application start here"""
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()

        self.protocol("WM_DELETE_WINDOW", self.on_close)
        self.title("Simple App")
        self.init_ui()
        self.set_values()

    def init_ui(self):
        
        w = ttk.Frame(self, padding=8)
       
        r = 0
        c = 1
        self.lstItems = tk.Listbox(w)
        self.lstItems.bind("<<ListboxSelect>>", self.on_listbox_select)
        self.lstItems.grid(row=r, column=c, padx=5, pady=5)
        
        w.grid(row=0, column=0, sticky=tk.N+tk.W+tk.S+tk.E)

    def set_values(self):

        self.lstItems.delete(0, tk.END)
        index = 0
        self.dict_items = {}

        #simulate a recordset the fields are: pk, name, enable,
        #if enable == 0 paint line gray
        rs = [(1,"Albert",1),
              (2,"Michel",1),
              (3,"Drake",0),
              (4,"Alan",1),
              (5,"George",0)]

        if rs:
            for i in rs:
                s = "{:}".format(i[1])
                self.lstItems.insert(tk.END, s)
                if i[2] != 1:
                    self.lstItems.itemconfig(index, {"bg":"light gray"})
                self.dict_items[index] = i[0]
                index += 1
                          
  
    def on_listbox_select(self, evt=None):

        if self.lstItems.curselection():

            index = self.lstItems.curselection()[0]
            pk = self.dict_items.get(index)
            s = self.lstItems.get(index)
            
            print("on_listbox_select: index = {0}, pk = {1} values = {2}".format(index, pk, s))
           
    def on_close(self,evt=None):
        """Close all"""
        if messagebox.askokcancel(self.title(), "Do you want to quit?", parent=self):
            self.destroy()

def main():

    app = App()
    app.mainloop()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

[image]

Comment: First of all thanks for your hard effort, If I'm understanding correctly you suggesting to create a dict object and use the listbox item index as the key for extracting the user id in this current position? I'll try that right away and give an update